# How to avoid onChange changing state straight away?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my ReactJS app I have submit form with one input field, that I want to keep generic:

```
if (questions[this.state.currentDialog].entry)
  return (
    <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
      <label>{toWrite.label}</label>
      {' '}
      <input
        name={toWrite.name}
        onChange={this.onInputChange}
      />
      {' '}
      <input type='submit' value='Send it >'/>
    </form>
  );
```

And my `onInputChange` looks like this:

```
onInputChange = (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.name == 'name') {
    this.setState({
      surveyState: {
        name: evt.target.value,
        change: this.state.surveyState.change,
      }
    });
  };
  if (evt.target.name == 'change') {
    this.setState({
      surveyState: {
        name: this.state.surveyState.name,
        change: evt.target.value,
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Right now the `surveyState` is change at every time that you will write in something, but you may skip submitting the form wit another generic button, but the state is already changed by `onInputChange`, and will be displayed in next state view, that is triggered by `skip` button. How to avoid this?

Comment: Why don't you just update your state on form submission instead of input change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it to a temporary state object.

```
onInputChange = (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.name === 'name') {
    this.setState({
      tempState: {
        name: evt.target.value,
      }
    });
  };
  if (evt.target.name === 'change') {
    this.setState({
      tempState: {
        change: evt.target.value,
      }
    });
  };
};
```

On submit save it to the real one, on skip you don't have to do anything or just clear the tempState:

```
onFormSubmit = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();

  this.setState(state => ({
    surveyState: {
      ...state.surveyState,
      ...state.tempState,
    }
  }));
}
```

Comment: I was sure that it will be good approach, but, because of some reason, I am getting input with value in next view :/

Comment: Because of some reason, `tempState` is still a value of the `input` field in next view...

Comment: In that case clear tempState - `this.setState({ tempState: { name: '', change: '' } })` where you need to (skip or submit)

Comment: Dominic, it sounds good, but the state mutates on next rendering, not at the one I need. And `this.state` does not work for me.

Comment: At the final i used `document.getElementById("clearMe").reset();` on the form, every time generic button is clicked, and used `tempState`. Thanks!

Comment: No prob but you shouldn't need to do that, it's because your components aren't "controlled", they should have `value={this.state.tempState.name}` and `value={this.state.tempState.change}` so that they are controlled by state

Comment: Yes, but how can I deal with delayed state mutation? I didnt find effective solution for this.

Comment: Dominic, I used calback on state update `this.setState({ tempState: { name: '', change: '', opinion: this.state.surveyState.opinion } }, () => { this.state });` and it didnt update the state :/

Comment: The callback is just for when the state has finished being set, I think you need to set up some example code somewhere (even if it's not working with some comments) for me to understand at what point you need to clear the state

Answer (score -1):

If you have two properties in your `surveyState` then you need to update both like `value` and `change` in your case if you don't wish so then separate them from `surveyState` and declare as separate state.

What I did is, used `...` spread operator which will bring you object as it is and then passed new property value. Here it will add new property value if not exists else update the same.

This will perform same functionality what you trying to acheive

```
onInputChange = (evt) => {
   if (evt.target.name == 'name') {
       this.name = evt.target.value
   };
   if (evt.target.name == 'change') {
      this.change = evt.target.value 
   };
};
Using `this` variable only to avoid re-rendering but onlt if you are using this state value for manupulation.
```

then `onFormSubmit`

```
const surveyState = {
    name = this.name,
    change = this.change
}
this.setState({surveyState })
```